# How to integrate spherical harmonics and an additional function?

Tags: integration, mathematical-physics, spherical-harmonics

I am attempting to solve an impossibly difficult (to me) integral, if you can offer any advice or help in any way then please do; your assistance is greatly appreciated.

The integral(s) are;

$$I(\ell',\ell) = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi}\,{\rm d}\phi\,{\rm d}\theta  \ \ Y_{\ell',m}^{*}(\theta,\phi) \, Y_{\ell,m}(\theta,\phi)\ \  \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(1-\frac{\gamma}{\beta})\cos(\theta)^2}} $$

Where $ Y_{\ell,m}(\theta,\phi)$ is the spherical harmonic for $\ell,m$, and $^*$ denotes the complex conjugate.

Even confining myself to the $(\ell,\ell',m) = (0,0,0)$ case is not obvious to me;  Since $Y_{0,0}^{*}(\theta,\phi) = Y_{0,0}(\theta,\phi) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}$ we have

$$
I(0,0) = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi}\,{\rm d}\phi \,{\rm d}\theta  \,\frac{1}{4\pi}   \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(1-\frac{\gamma}{\beta})\cos(\theta)^2}}  \\
$$

$$
= \int_0^{\pi}\, {\rm d}\theta  \, \frac{2\pi}{4\pi}   \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(1-\frac{\gamma}{\beta})\cos(\theta)^2}} \\
$$

$$
= \int_0^{\pi}\,{\rm d}\theta  \, \frac{1}{2}   \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(1-\frac{\gamma}{\beta})\cos(\theta)^2}} 
$$

I've never been particularly adept at spotting the "trick" substitution. As far as I can see, any substitution involving $\cos(\theta)$ will result in terms dependent upon $\theta$ which then invalidates the point of the substitution in the first place.

For the curious, the function $I(\ell',\ell)$ is taken from equation 2.14 of the [paper](http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.184.713) by R. A. Faulkner 1969.

---

****EDIT** based upon the suggestions of @tired and @winther about this being similar to an elliptical function.**

By making the substitution $\cos(\theta)^2 = 1- \sin(\theta)^2$;

$$\sqrt{1-(1-\frac{\gamma}{\beta})\cos(\theta)^2} = \sqrt{1-(1-\frac{\gamma}{\beta})(1- \sin(\theta)^2)}$$

$$=\sqrt{\frac{\gamma}{\beta} + (1-\frac{\gamma}{\beta})\sin(\theta)^2}$$

$$=(\frac{\gamma}{\beta})^{\frac{1}{2}} \sqrt{1 + (\frac{\beta}{\gamma}-1)\sin(\theta)^2}$$

$$=(\frac{\gamma}{\beta})^{\frac{1}{2}} \sqrt{1 - (1-\frac{\beta}{\gamma})\sin(\theta)^2}$$

which is the same form as the ["complete elliptic integral of the first kind"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind) for the $\ell',\ell,m=0,0,0$ case.
So that we get;

$$
I(0,0)=\frac{1}{2(\frac{\gamma}{\beta})^{\frac{1}{2}}} \int_0^{\pi}\,{\rm d}\theta  \,   \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - (1-\frac{\beta}{\gamma})\sin(\theta)^2}} 
$$

With the complete elliptic integral of the first kind [being](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind);

$$K(k)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \frac{{\rm d}\theta}{\sqrt{[1-k^{2}\sin(\theta)^2]}} $$

So, if I'm not mistaken (This is where you correct me), as between $0$ and $\pi$ sin is symmetrical about $\frac{\pi}{2}$, giving a factor of 2, then;

$$ I(0,0) = \frac{1}{2(\frac{\gamma}{\beta})^{\frac{1}{2}}} K( (1-\frac{\beta}{\gamma}) )$$ ?

And then for the general case, I am left with;
$$I(\ell',\ell) =\frac{1}{(\frac{\gamma}{\beta})^{\frac{1}{2}}} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi}\,{\rm d}\phi\,{\rm d}\theta  \ \frac{Y_{\ell',m}^{*}(\theta,\phi) \, Y_{\ell,m}(\theta,\phi)}{\sqrt{1-(1-\frac{\gamma}{\beta})\sin(\theta)^2}} $$

Comment: The $I(0,0)$ integral is roughly the definition of the [complete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind) (a non-elementary function) and it's not possible to express it in "normal" (elementary) functions other than as a infinite sum/product of such functions.

Comment: As for "solving" such integrals in general you can see for example [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582738/integrate-this-spherical-harmonics-function/1582767#1582767) (I use quotemarks here as this is a way of writing the solution as an infinite series, but this is often the best you can do)

Comment: since higher spherical harmonics are essentialy given $\sin(\theta)^i\cos(\theta)^j$ times a trivial $\phi$ dependent factor everything will boil down to elliptic integrals in the end

Comment: Ah. Thanks Winther, I shall check that out.

Comment: @tired , so the question really is "how does one solve elliptic integrals"?

Comment: i would say how to express integrals of  powers of trigonometric functions times $1/\sqrt{1-a \cos(\theta)^2}$ in terms of elliptic functions

Comment: some integrals will be elementary, for example if you take $0,1,m$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do one of the non-elementary integrals (we assume $\alpha^2\equiv1-\gamma/\beta>0$):

Take $(2,0,m)$. then the integral takes the form (due to complex conjugation the integral corresponding to $m$ will be always trivial)

$$
I(2,0,m)=C\int_0^\pi d\theta \frac{3\cos(\theta)^2-1}{\sqrt{1-\alpha^2\cos(\theta)^2}}
$$

Here $C$ is some constant.

Now employing a substitution $\theta\rightarrow \Theta-\pi/2$ and usinng the symmetry of the integrand this boils down to

$$
I(2,0,m)=2C\int_0^{\pi/2} d\Theta \frac{3\sin(\Theta)^2-1}{\sqrt{1-\alpha^2\sin(\Theta)^2}}=2C\left(\int_0^{\pi/2}d\Theta \frac{3\sin(\Theta)^2}{\sqrt{1-\alpha^2\sin(\Theta)^2}}-\int_0^{\pi/2}d\Theta \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\alpha^2\sin(\Theta)^2}}\right)\\=2C\left(\frac{-3}{\alpha^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}d\Theta \frac{1-\alpha^2\sin(\Theta)^2-1}{\sqrt{1-\alpha^2\sin(\Theta)^2}}-\int_0^{\pi/2}d\Theta \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\alpha^2\sin(\Theta)^2}}\right)\\
=2C\left(\frac{-3}{\alpha^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}d\Theta \sqrt{1-\alpha^2\sin(\Theta)^2}+\left(\frac{3}{\alpha^2}-1\right)\int_0^{\pi/2}d\Theta \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\alpha^2\sin(\Theta)^2}}\right)
$$

Employing the definiton of the [complete elliptic integrals of the first and second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) we can rewrite this as

$$
I(2,0,m)=-\frac{6C}{\alpha^2}E(\alpha)+2C\left(\frac{3}{\alpha^2}-1\right)K(\alpha)
$$

Comment: Yes, I think γ/β cannot be greater than 1, γ at least cannot be greater than 1 and β is a variational parameter so I have no idea what It will be  ,so this is looking good.
Thanks, this is very helpful, If you were in my department I would buy you a cake @tired. (cakes for all really).

Comment: While this is great, this is an easier example than the "elementary" I(1,0m)....

Comment: never mind, was being stupid, I realised that I(1,0,m)=0.
Thanks again!

Comment: When considering the $I(4,0,m=0)$ case, a $\sin(\theta)^4 / [1-\alpha \sin(\theta)^2]^{\frac{1}{2}}$ term also occurs. Any ideas on how to wrangle that into the elliptic form?

Comment: you can boil it down into a form which contains an integral like this:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644872/solving-int-0-pi-2-sin2-theta-sqrt1-k2-sin2-thetad-theta/1650863#1650863. At the moment i don't see an easier solution but there should be one

Comment: i think the user @achille hui could help us out here...

Comment: Ah yes @tired, I see how to boil it down to end up with the equation as in your link. 
I'll work through that now.
I know that the next I(l',l) term is going to be I(6,0,m) so I don't relish the $cos^6$ that will accost me then though haha.
Thanks again, without your help I would have had a very frustrating time attempting this.